# recovering the deleted content in a .tex file

Tags: texworks

I accidently deleted a large part of my work on a .tex file. Unknowingly, i saved the file , ran the typeset once and closed it. Hence the content is deleted from the pdf too. Is there any way to retrieve the deleted content. I check the previous version of the file too but it is not available either. Somebody please help. I am desperate.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! I'm sorry to hear that happened to you—losing so much progress always feels bad. Unfortunately, your .tex file is just like any text file, so unless you have a backup somewhere, there's no way to recover the lost parts. It's a painful learning experience, but one that hopefully won't occur again when you start backing up files regularly

Comment: When you say 'previous version', do you just mean a single backup created by your editor or something? If you had it under version control, you could, of course, recover much of it (provided you committed changes relatively recently). Otherwise, unless what you've lost is valuable, you're probably out of luck. If it is valuable and you haven't done much on the machine since it happened, shut down and contact a file recovery service. Or there are programmes you can try on your own, but only work on a copy of the disk. If you've been using the disk, useful data may not be recoverable.

Comment: My sympathies.There might be a small chance treating the medium where the file is stored as a write-protected raw device and looking at it via a hex editor. But beneath other things you need to be an an expert of the file system in question. In case data blocks holding parts of your .tex-file are spread all over the medium/data is fragmented and/or some stuff already got physically overwritten you might be out of luck. In any case this is not really a TeX question but a question of data recovery. You might get better answers in a data-recovery-forum than in a TeX-forum. Good luck.

Comment: Probably the software used for editing the .tex-file did create a .bak-file? Some, but not many text editors do that.